# Can someone point out a small logic error to me?

Tags: c

I am doing the following program out of a book and don't understand where I am going wrong with it. Can someone please point out to me some mistake in logic that I am missing?

Develop a program that will input the miles driven and gallons used for each tankful.
The program should calculate and display the miles per gallon obtained for each tankful. After processing all input information, the program should calculate and print the combined miles per gallon obtained for all tankfuls.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    int total = 0, count = 0;
    float gallons_used, mpg, miles;
    while(gallons_used != -1) {
    printf("Enter the gallons used (-1 to end): ");
        scanf("%f", &gallons_used);
        printf("Enter the miles driven: ");
        scanf("%f", &miles);
        mpg = miles / gallons_used;
        printf("Miles / gallon for this tank was %f\n", mpg);
        total += mpg;
        count++;
    }
    total /= count;
    printf("Average miles to the gallon was: %d\n", total);
    return 0;
}
```

Now, It appears that I have the loop just right, up until the point I exit it with the value of -1 because it still asks for the mileage of that tank, and obviously inputting it completely throws off the total at the end.

Comment: that's because you do not exit just after reading gallons_used from user. put a break statement just after this instead of in while condition.

Comment: You check the value of `gallons_used`, but you never initialized it!  What if it happens to start with value `-1`??

Comment: Or at least just check `gallons_used < 0`, if so, break out of the loop

Comment: I don't reccomend that kind of comparison with float types... it will cause you trouble sometimes, comparing float to integers might lead to  some bug in some cases, usually when working with float the comparison is: if(abs((float_variable - value) < small_error_value))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
while(true) {
printf("Enter the gallons used (-1 to end): ");
    scanf("%f", &gallons_used);
    printf("Enter the miles driven: ");
    scanf("%f", &miles);
    if(gallons_used== -1 )break;
    mpg = miles / gallons_used;
    printf("Miles / gallon for this tank was %f\n", mpg);
    total += mpg;
    count++;
}
```

Comment: timmy's answer is better it doesnt ask for miles if you enter -1 for galons :)

Answer (score 2):

You can use an infinite loop and break it just in case gallons_used = -1

```
for(;;) { // <-- infinite loop
    printf("Enter the gallons used (-1 to end): ");
    scanf("%f", &gallons_used);
    if (gallons_used == -1)
        break; // <-- exit the loop
    printf("Enter the miles driven: ");
    scanf("%f", &miles);
    mpg = miles / gallons_used;
    printf("Miles / gallon for this tank was %f\n", mpg);
    total += mpg;
    count++;
}
```

Comment: This does not work either, it does the same as it was before, with it still asking for the last input.

Comment: @user3765259: asks for the input but exits in case it is -1 so it should work

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    int total = 0, count = 0;
    float gallons_used, mpg, miles;
    while(gallons_used != -1) {
    printf("Enter the gallons used (-1 to end): ");
        scanf("%f", &gallons_used);
        if (gallons_used < 0)             // check gallons_used
            break;
        printf("Enter the miles driven: ");
        scanf("%f", &miles);
        mpg = miles / gallons_used;
        printf("Miles / gallon for this tank was %f\n", mpg);
        total += mpg;
        count++;
    }
    total /= count;
    printf("Average miles to the gallon was: %d\n", total);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using `gallons_used` uninitialized. Using uninitialized variables invokes **undefined behavior**. You need to initialize it first before comparing it in `while`'s conditional expression. You can do this as

```
printf("Enter the gallons used (-1 to end): ");
scanf("%f", &gallons_used);           // Reading value for gallons_used

while(gallons_used != -1) {
    printf("Enter the miles driven: ");
    scanf("%f", &miles);
    mpg = miles / gallons_used;
    printf("Miles / gallon for this tank was %f\n", mpg);
    total += mpg;
    count++;
    printf("Enter the gallons used (-1 to end): ");
    scanf("%f", &gallons_used);
}
```